# Multiple Alignment in TextView

Tags: android, textview, alignment

How to make multiple alignment in textview?
Like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROoRk.jpg)

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return Html.fromHtml("add your html formated text here", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
        } else {
            return Html.fromHtml("add your html formated text here");
        }
```